# The [indicator] indicates to BURN!

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indicator) has no usage guidance, 3 watchers, and holds a total of 339 questions at the time of writing this question.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tag is ambiguous and does not describe the contents of the question. I have no idea what the [indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indicator) says about the question.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Indicators in some sense are on-topic for the site, and else it has a different meaning which can be off-topic for this site.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, it doesn't. It cannot tell much about the question's problem, language, or any other framework. It can mean to indicate something in the code or to create an indicator (e.g. for your view pager or slideshow which can be classified as broad).

Also, you cannot be an expert in the tag. If there's a problem indicating something in the code, you should tag it with the language or appropriate framework.
An edit to tell the varieties of the question this tag holds

- [How to include needed C library using gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016815/how-to-include-needed-c-library-using-gcc) < - A C quesiton
- [ASP.Net MVC Loading In Progress Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287014/asp-net-mvc-loading-in-progress-indicator)  < - A asp question
- [Changing the color of the whitespace indicator in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166903/changing-the-color-of-the-whitespace-indicator-in-visual-studio) < - question related to a software not programming related
- [All Levels of a Factor in a Model Matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560459/all-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-model-matrix-in-r) < - A R question
- [Where can I find information on integrating Java applications into the Ubuntu application indicator menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853665/where-can-i-find-information-on-integrating-java-applications-into-the-ubuntu-ap) < - A java question
- [Is there a possibility to show an icon for symbolic link resource in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399015/is-there-a-possibility-to-show-an-icon-for-symbolic-link-resource-in-eclipse) < - related to eclipse not programming related
- [html Image Title only working on mouse over the sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089040/html-image-title-only-working-on-mouse-over-the-sides) < - html/css related question
- [How to change the label of a MenuItem in a PyGTK application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981004/how-to-change-the-label-of-a-menuitem-in-a-pygtk-application) < - Python related question

This list tells the ambiguity of the tag. It is very broad.

Comment: Could you possibly add some links to sample questions that demonstrate e.g. ambiguity in order to support your assertions here? That would make a much stronger case (not that I disagree, but at this point the content of any [tag:indicator] questions has been ignored)... For all I know, `indicator` could be a framework and just missing usage guidance.

Comment: The definition of indicator is "a thing that indicates the state or level of something". That's so broad that includes even error messages and debug messages and whatnot.

Comment: @MaxLanghof there's no need actually because if you click on the tag and go to the list of questions, you'll see many varieties of questions in different languages mostly in ios and android to indicate pages in a viewpager. I'll still edit to add extra questions to support my statements

Comment: While there are many different uses (indicator variables in SAS, UI elements, ...), quite a few of the questions seem related to some trading platform ([metatrader4], [mql4], [tradingview-api]). So there might be some meaningful concept called "indicator" in that domain.

Comment: @JiriTousek I'm falling to see how? Can you link some questions that use the tag and the tag makes sense to tell about the question?

Comment: And to embedded systems programmers, indicator typically means a physical LED.

Comment: Questions about how to write code to set an indicator in an embedded system is very much on-topic. However, I can't find any such posts using the tag.

Comment: These burninate requests are exhausting mainly because of the amount of misinformation they tend to contain, both in the post itself and in the comments. Where in the world did you get the impression that embedded programming is off-topic for Stack Overflow? It is emphatically not. Even Arduino programming questions are on-topic here. The existence of another, more specialized Stack Exchange site does not make questions about that topic magically off-topic for Stack Overflow. Besides, Arduino is not the only embedded development environment that exists in the world.

Comment: @CodyGray okay, I didn't know that. You can ask questions that are related to code on StackOverflow like lighting led's in a pattern in code etc. But hardware configurations and other help are off-topic for StackOverflow and I gave an example there, not justified that Audrino is the only embedded system in the world, an example. Also, why to assume that _These burninate requests are exhausting mainly because of the amount of misinformation they tend to contain,_ The question does not contain any false information, the comment was my mistake, I wasn't clear. I apologize for that.

Comment: You don't have to judge by the misinformation in the comments below. They will say what they need to say. You have to judge the request by the information provided in the question.

Comment: I’ve grown very tired of the “no one can be an expert in this tag” meme as well.

Comment: @CodyGray _I’ve grown very tired of the “no one can be an expert in this tag” meme as well._ Because it's wrong? Or because it needs to be repeated over and over again? If the former, could you elaborate? I don't see how someone who has expertise in programming status indicators in WPF could bring that expertise to bear when programming a web-based status indicator (for example).

Comment: Because it’s meaningless, @Zev, and seduces far too many people into advocating for the deletion of useful tags. The situation you describe is why we allow questions to have multiple tags. WPF developers will naturally include the [wpf] tag in their searches.

Comment: @window.document See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203366/how-do-you-access-the-pine-script-code-behind-a-public-indicator-in-tradingview for a question about an "indicator" on a trading platform. I'm no domain expert but it seems they use the word to describe a programmable/computed number or series to display or act upon. Also evidenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545674/clicking-refresh-sometimes-leads-to-different-custom-indicator-results).

Comment: And here are [some questions that combine "indicator" with a trading platform tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tradingview-api+indicator+or+metatrader4+indicator+or+mql4+indicator).

Comment: @JiriTousek That question seems more relevant when tagged with [mql14] only. [Indicator] is not a stable topic on many questions. It is mainly a component. Be it any UI/hardware/trading component or other

Comment: _they use the word to describe a programmable/computed number or series to display or act upon._ They have to use the word then. All I'm seeing is [indicator] there is used to locate something [under this bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTBF2.png) @JiriTousek

Answer (score 1):

I thought after sorting by votes I would find all the good questions are for progress/activity indicator UI elements. Nope!

I propose to disambiguate and break this into three tags and burn the original [indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indicator) tag:

[progress-indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-indicator) (alternate: [progress-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-bar)) already exists to receive progress questions.

[activity-indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/activity-indicator) already exists to receive the busy notification

[affordance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/affordance) would be much better for can-perform-action glyphs

[status-indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-indicator) or [selection-indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selection-indicator) would take care of almost all the rest, but we probably don't have to do that at all as it doesn't add much to the question anymore and no tag at all for these seems better.

Comment: Why we need another tag for a UI component? Why can't we just tag it with the language we are implementing it in and mention other necessities about indicating something in the question? That way, the question will gain more traction

Comment: @window.document: Considering that two of the three tags already exist ...

Comment: We don't need to disambiguate this into three tags. That way it will narrow the search for these questions. We just need to burninate this tag and leave all the questions with the tags they were tagged with i.e the language and the frameworks.

Comment: @window.document: Feel free to post a competing answer; but having done burns I can guarantee you that if this tag is burned the first two (targeting extant tags) will be partially applied anyway.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea why people include this information that they have done it in the past or they are experienced. I can tell that by your profile and I respect you all equally independent of the reputation. Can you explain why it will be partially applied anyway? And why should I hold on a guarantee?

Comment: [status-indicator] or [selection-indicator] tags don't exist. [activity-indicator] tag holds exactly 0 watchers. [affordance] tag also doesn't exist. [progress-indicator] also has 0 watchers. Which tags you want to disambiguate the [indicator] tag into? The only worthy tag from all of the tags you ever mentioned in your question is [progress-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progress-bar)

Comment: @window.document: Because while actually doing burnination, when we remove tags we look for related tags for the question so it ends up with more than just a language tag. With only 300-odd questions, the auto-bot tag remover will probably not be used.

Comment: Having now read two dictionary definitions and a wikipedia article, I somewhat understand what 'affordance' means, but I 100% would never have used it in this scenario, nor would I expect a non-native-English-speaker to have reached for that word.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: I'm open to suggestions. This is the only context for which I know the word anyway.

Comment: I don't see why it's necessary at all, frankly. If it's an issue with glyphs/icons, then [glyph] or [icon] (if such exist) would be the appropriate tag. The function of those glyphs/icons isn't really relevant enough to warrant a tag, I think.

Comment: I very much dislike the idea of introducing [tag:affordance]. [Fine for UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affordance). On Stack Overflow it's off-topic.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas It's quite commonly used in UX. I've never heard it used outside of that context, even as a native English speaker.